# How to handle downtime scenario while spring remote authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have Spring MVC based website where to authenticate a user I need to call a Third-party API (which communicates with our core user database for all the applications), and authenticate the user there.
I am able to do this successfully, only that when the ThirdParty API is down for some reason, my website bombs too whenever any visitor tries to login or signup.

I am calling the remote API like this:

`ResponseEntity<LoginApiResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, LoginApiResponse.class);`

Here, LoginApiResponse.class is a bean that contains the UserDetails and other information that the response from there might contain.

The Bean roughly looks like this:

```
public class LoginApiResponse {
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;    
    private String responseStatus;
    private UserModel userModel;
    ... ...
}
```

I have a CustomRestResponseErrorHandler which handles the error on my site.
However, when the Third-party site is down, a maintenance page is configured to be returned on any kind of request, so the response that I get will be of type `text/html` with response status `200 OK`. Hence, no exception encountered here and my `CustomRestResponseErrorHandler` does not come into play. Rather, the code bombs when it is unable to convert the `text/html` type response to `LoginApiResponse` as per the call. And it throws,

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.habba.web.rest.registration.LoginApiResponse] and content type [text/html]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:811)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:795)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:574)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:547)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:468)
```

How do I avoid this from happening and determine earlier the unavailability of the ThirdPartyApi?

Answer (score 0):

From what you said it seems the content type of the normal response you receive from you API is `application/json`. Instead of using `ResponseEntity<LoginApiResponse>` you could use `ResponseEntity<Object>` and check the content type using `responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType()`. If the content type is not what you expect you can take the appropriate action.

Comment: the given approach doesn't work for me either. Gives me the same error, no suitable HttpMessageConverter found. Tried using String type, works that way but that's not what i want.